# Macbook Pro not loading insecure webpages/content in any browser

Tags: macbook-pro, network, dns, http

Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I've run out of options.

Within the past week or two my web browsers will not load anything unless it has 'https' in front of it. I am a web developer and work with Google's jQuery hosted libraries quite often, one of my sites isn't appearing properly for me because the script is loading from `http` rather than `https` -- I can't even browse to the script without `https`.

I know this isn't a problem with the script because I have co-workers who have it working just fine, it just seems to be a problem with my macbook. I've tried Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari all with the same results.

I've tried clearing my DNS cache using `dscachutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;` and restarting, but no luck.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening or what I can do to fix it? I would just reinstall Chrome, but it's happening in all browsers.

**EDIT**

This is a screenshot of the errors in the browser console. Not your average `Cross Content` error.[image]

Comment: Do you use any anti-virus or VPN? Maybe they are the cause of your error. Try to lower your security to accept unsecure connection as well. If that didn't help, you can check some help I have found on apple support (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6467321?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: Check System Preferences -> Network -> (however you connect to the internet: WiFi, Ethernet, etc.) -> Advanced... -> Proxies for any activated proxies as well. A dead HTTP proxy would neatly explain HTTPS being spared.